# Не могу авторизироваться в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Проект создан через Homestead на Laravel 7.0. Сгенерировал все контроллеры и шаблоны для аутентификации командой

```
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui vue --auth
```

После чего зарегистрировался в проекте. Запись в таблице БД создалась. После чего пробую авторизироваться на странице `/login`. Происходит следующее: Контроллер `Login` отрабатывает корректно и перенаправляет на контроллер `/home`. Но у этого контроллера в конструкторе прописал `$this->middleware('auth');`. И при его отрабатывании меня снова кидает на страницу авторизации, без малейшего намека на проблему.

P.S. Только что проверил свой проект через WAMP (на windows без homestead) и всё работает. То-есть проблема в самой настройке `Homestead`. Проверил каталоги сессий и тд. Всё на месте. Кто-нибудь знает из-за чего может возникнуть такая проблема?

Comment: `$this->middleware('auth')`, говорит о том, что только зарегестрированный пользвотель может посетить акшены даного контроллера

Comment: Я понимаю. А как мне понять почему меня не пускает дальше, если авторизация прошла успешно?

Comment: Проверьте что у вас создаются сессия и данные в БД для авторизации пользователя, а также права на папку storage/framework/sessions; подозреваю что у вас авторизация не сохраняется и поэтому вы перенаправляетесь снова на /login. Это можно сделать с помощью вызова Auth::user() ПОСЛЕ логина пользователя и посмотреть что в нём.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я понял, в чем проблема. Виноват. Структура пользовательской таблицы не соответствует миграции Laravel. Извините, что потратил впустую ваше время.

Answer (score 0):

в 6 и 7 ларе нет команды 
php artisan make:auth

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

7 лара - https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication

6 лара - https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authentication

последний раз она была в 5.8 - https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication

Comment: Зато есть вот это: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#included-routing
Что по сути вроде делает тоже самое. Создает контроллеры, шаблоны и всю логику авторизации, регистрации и восстановления пароля.
Поправил вопрос